# Vuex State not Updating When reducing state value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am trying to update state using vuex, my codes are as follows

ACTION

```
    async SET_DISTANCE_DURATION({ commit }, data) {
      commit("DURATION_DISTANCE", data);
    },
```

MUTATION

```
    DURATION_DISTANCE(state, res) {
      state.prevDuration = state.Duration;
      state.Distance = res.distance;
      state.Duration = res.duration;
    },
```

STATE

```
      Duration: null,
```

The problem I am facing is when i increase the duration it works without a problem, but when i attempt to decrease the duration the value i pass comes upto the `MUTATION` but doesn't get updated within the state,

MY ADD DURATION DISPATCH

```
    current_total = current_total + temp2;
        let da = { distance: total_distance, duration: current_total 
       };
    this.$store.dispatch("SET_DISTANCE_DURATION", da);
```

MY REDUCE DURATION DISPATCH

```
        current_total = current_total - removed_duration;
    let da = { distance: total_distance, duration: current_total };
    this.$store.dispatch("SET_DISTANCE_DURATION", da);
```

Comment: Sorry, don't think I will have the answer for this as dispatching an action will not know if we are increasing or decreasing the value. The code you are posting looks perfect. So it must be somewhere else that causing this. How about placing the two codes right after the other and check for state update?

Comment: @Ithh89vt i did the increase time dispatch and it works perfectly, but when i tried the decrease dispatch and followed the data through `console.logs` the data reached all the way to the mutation, its just the state that doesn't get updated.

Comment: Yeah, I got that from your question. My suspect is the other part of your code causing this rather than the increase/decrease part as it shouldn't make any different. So to prove this, if you can change the `+` to `-` in your working increase function to see if it is working still. eg `current_total = current_total - temp2;`

Comment: @Ithh89vt true, ill check my codes for any other errors thanks